# Where should I update state to get the correct readout from the API?

Tags: json, reactjs, rest, api, lifecycle

I have have a big project to complete for an interview for my first job as a developer, so I am **a)** inexperienced and **b)** without the time to do any drastic refactoring (e.g. using Hooks).

My task it to pull data from an API and generate some charts. I have (finally) figured out how to get the data I need using axios, but am having a very strange problem when trying to access the object.

The parent, `<App />`, sets the object to state like so:

```js
  onDateChange = async date => {
    const response = await fastapi.get(`/${date}`)
    this.setState({apiData:response.data})
  }
```

When I log the state I see exactly what I expect. So I go over to the child component (`<DataDisplay />`) where I need to split the object into several variables and this is where things start getting messy. I try to `console.log` the data at `this.props.apiData.site_hours` and there's no problem. I get back a small object of two key-value pairs: `{"inside": 3.19765, "outside": 4.64378}`. But as soon as I try to log `this.props.apiData.site_hours.inside` it tells me inside is undefined!

I asked a friend who is a very experienced programmer albeit not familiar with React and he said it is likely that it is just undefined at the time I am logging it. Very strange since I can get the information one level up in the object, but when I burrow down one level, nothing! So I tried moving my `console.log` around and sure enough, when I place it in `componentDidUpdate()`, `site_hours.inside` exists! So I tried using `componentDidUpdate()` to set state, but was promptly told by the machine that this is a very very bad idea.

So clearly this is an issue with the lifecycle and the order in which I'm trying to do things, but none of my research has turned up anything useful! I find it mind boggling that my call to this object will return only some of the information and not all of it. Please help!

https://github.com/erasebegin/react-projects/tree/master/tharsus-interface/src

Comment: It may be that you are somehow triggering an unintentional re-render and the data is undefined by the time you see it logged, i see you are setting state a lot, keep in mind state changes trigger a re-render

Comment: in your `DataDisplay` is there a reason why you are setting the data passed as props to state in the componentDidMount  (you are triggering a re-render here) or setting it to state at all? can you not just display this data from `props` directly? i notice that you are not actually _updating_ (or using state otherwise) at all from that component...so do you really need state there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED => try this and see if you can log the props from the child component:

```
import React from "react";
import MovementDataDisplay from "./MovementDataDisplay";
import OverviewDataDisplay from "./OverviewDataDisplay";
import DistributionDataDisplay from "./DistributionDataDisplay";

class DataDisplay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { passAPIData } = this.props
    const {siteHours, movingHours} = passAPIData

    console.log(siteHours, movingHours)

    if (this.props.NavState === "movement") {
        return (
          <div className="chart-container">
            <MovementDataDisplay
              Data={passAPIData}
              Title="Site Hours"
              Labels={['inside','outside']}
            />
            <MovementDataDisplay
              Data={[1,3]}
              Title="Moving Hours"
            />
          </div>
        );
      } else if (this.props.NavState === "overview") {
        return (
          <div className="chart-container">
            <OverviewDataDisplay
              Data={[3.3176110809420893, 4.18238891905791]}
              Title="Site Hours"
            />
            <OverviewDataDisplay
              Data={[3.9176110809420893, 4.18238891905791]}
              Title="Moving Hours"
            />
          </div>
        );
      } else if (this.props.NavState === "distribution") {
        return <DistributionDataDisplay />;
      }
    }
}

export default DataDisplay;
```

without pulling the repo and debugging it, or running it (admittedly) my guess is that you are causing a re-render when you set the state in the `componentDidMount` of the child component and losing that value (just a guess) - here i have removed `state` all together (i can't see how it's needed) and the `componentDidMount` and am logging the values you are looking for from props directly. If those values are set in the parent state and passed as props, there isn't any reason i can see (from what you currently have) that you need to re-set them to state again in the child. you don't even seem to be using state in the child for anything except to set props to it so far, and unless those values are going to change locally from within this child component... you can (and should) just read them from the props of the parent where they *are* defined, updated, and passed.

**UPDATED** AGAIN (after fiddling with the actual code ;) )

check this and see if it solves your problem. i added comments for little changes i made:

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import DataDisplay from "./components/DataDisplay";
import "./styles/App.css";
import fastapi from './api/fastapi'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      userDate: "",
      apiData: {}, // this was set to a [] but it's data type is a actually an {}
      navState: "overview"
    };
    this.setNavState = this.setNavState.bind(this);
  }

  setNavState(nav) {
    // when triggering this from the UI it causes a state change, and a re-render
    const btnArr = ["overview", "movement", "distribution"];
    this.setState({ navState: btnArr[nav] });

    // this needs to be reset
    this.onDateChange(this.state.userDate)
  }

  onDateChange = async date => {
    const response = await fastapi.get(`/${date}`)
    console.log('onDateChange response.data', response.data)

    this.setState({ 
      apiData: response.data, 
      userDate: date ? date : this.state.userDate // you were not setting this but you will need it for when setNavState runs
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log("new state is ",this.state.apiData) // you should see this
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Nav getNav={this.setNavState} getDate={this.onDateChange} />
        <DataDisplay NavState={this.state.navState} apiData={this.state.apiData}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

DateDisplay.js

```
import React from "react";
import MovementDataDisplay from "./MovementDataDisplay";
import OverviewDataDisplay from "./OverviewDataDisplay";
import DistributionDataDisplay from "./DistributionDataDisplay";

class DataDisplay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("from DataDisplay: ", this.props.apiData)
    const { apiData : { site_hours = {} }} = this.props
    const {inside = 0, outside = 0} = site_hours // defaults to avoid breaking if there is no data here (prior to selecting date for ex)

    console.log(inside, outside) // i can see these logs in the child :) 

    if (this.props.NavState === "movement") {
        return (
          <div className="chart-container">
            <MovementDataDisplay
              Data={[inside, outside]} // you are putting the entire 'this.state' here (a big object), but it seems to want a simple array
              Title="Site Hours"
              Labels={['inside','outside']}
            />
            <MovementDataDisplay
              Data={[1,3]}
              Title="Moving Hours"
            />
          </div>
        );
      } else if (this.props.NavState === "overview") {
        return (
          <div className="chart-container">
            <OverviewDataDisplay
              Data={[3.3176110809420893, 4.18238891905791]}
              Title="Site Hours"
            />
            <OverviewDataDisplay
              Data={[3.9176110809420893, 4.18238891905791]}
              Title="Moving Hours"
            />
          </div>
        );
      } else if (this.props.NavState === "distribution") {
        return <DistributionDataDisplay />; // you need to pass this some data of course :) 
      }
    }
}

export default DataDisplay;
```

I can see the logs in the child, no state needed. The issue *I saw* and IDK if this is what you were talking about, was the page breaking when clicking between the Overview/Movement/Distribution charts. This is because your api response is stored to a local state in a parent component, when you update the state by calling `setNavState` in the Nav you trigger a re-render in that parent and the state is lost, and you need to refetch the data - the page breaks because the data is no longer available to that child and there are no protections in place for it to handle not having data (this is something you should always code for for the record) so I

1) saved the date in state 
2) and re-fetch it in that same nav callback (this probably works because setState is async) 
3) added some default values to the child to prevent breaking

IF this app had a global state you could store the apiResponse there and not need to refetch, or you could store it in localstorage or even cookies to avoid a refetch. Global state being preferable.

Comment: You're absolutely right that I don't need to use state here, I just don't know any other way to access variables in `render()` unless it's from state or from props. Since I have to create a whole bunch of variables, I didn't want to do it right in the `render()` method for the sake of neatness. 
ANYWAY, I tried your solution (thank you!), but alas it is returning undefined for both siteHours and movingHours.

Comment: I forgot to mention something very important:
I get the same behaviour in the `<App />` component! When I try to log `this.state.apiData` I get the whole object. Then `this.state.apiData.site_hours` gets me the next object down, then `site_hours.inside` is undefined!
I guess maybe using state even in `<App /> is not a good idea, but that is the way a pro does it in a reference project....

Comment: It seems that I also get the expected result when logging `this.state.apiData.site_hours.inside` if I do it in the `onDateChange()` method in the `<App />` component. Please help, this is driving me batty!

Comment: will this work if i pull the repo and run it or are there some api keys used in the request that you have in a env file?

Comment: using state is fine to use in _any_ component, i was merely showing you it's not needed and is in fact probably causing a re-render which can sometimes cause problems, it's just something to understand about how state works... so i was trying to eliminate that being the culprit by removing it when it wasn't needed...i can't see anything in the code that's causing but i can try to run it and debug it

Comment: It will run, it's just that the api request causes a CORS error which I was only able to circumvent using a browser extension. When I hand it in for the interview they'll run it on their internal network so that won't be a problem. Postman gets it just fine. They just have some wacky setting on the server. I like what you did before with the destructuring, that will come in handy for what I'm trying to do. Um, I only know how to debug in theory. Very little practice  I guess this is a good opportunity to try!

Comment: yes i see the cors error, i installed the extension i will poke around a bit

Comment: and yes, as a developer a lot of your job is going to be in debugging so def get used to it! lol! it's actually how you learn a lot so don't shy away from it

Comment: okay i _think_ i see the issue you were having, going to update my answer. let me know if this was your issue.

Comment: I watched a few debugging videos in bed before I fell a sleep. I woke up ready to tackle this monster and found that you had already slain the beast while I slept! I can indeed log the information I need without a problem, but only using the destructuring technique that you have implemented here. If I try doing it the way I tried before: `apiData.site_hours.inside` I am still told it doesn't exist. I really thought dot notation was the way to go ‍♂️ Anyway, next time I run into trouble I'm going to put on my bug fighting armor and see if I can win! Thank you so much.

Comment: Please contact me by email: chris.james.haupt@gmail.com
I am leaving Switzerland soon so will be buying lots of chocolate to take home to friends and family. I would like to send you some.

Comment: @erasebegin, that is very thoughtful of you to want to send chocolates lol, however, it is not necessary  instead, to return the favor as you learn and grow as a developer... Help other developers out there just learning as was done for you, and has been done for me many times. Do it generously and with patience and empathy. That said your issue was not for notation, sit with the working code for awhile and study it. Go back to your old code and change one thing at a time and rerun it till you see where it's suddenly fixed (I wrote  lots of comnents) .

Comment: That said, if this solution works for you, kindly consider clicking the ✓ thus marking it as your accepted answer 

Comment: I spent lots of time looking over the things you changed and have just about come to understand how the destructuring works because I've been playing with it a lot today. I also see now the importance of setting default values for things. Thanks again, I will spread the kindness ^_^